# undefined method 'request' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) when trying to launch rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am setting up rails on an apple M1 computer and am trying to make sure the environment is all set up correctly. Everything looks good except for when I try to launch my rails console or server I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    12: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:301:in `activate_bin_path'
    11: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:301:in `synchronize'
    10: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `block in activate_bin_path'
     9: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:240:in `finish_resolve'
     8: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:423:in `resolve_current'
     7: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:411:in `resolve'
     6: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:189:in `resolve'
     5: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:193:in `rescue in resolve'
     4: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:193:in `raise'
     3: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:193:in `exception'
     2: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb:26:in `initialize'
     1: from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb:32:in `conflicting_dependencies'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/conflict.rb:47:in `conflicting_dependencies': undefined method `request' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Background:
Before I was getting this error, `rails c` *would* launch console, although I was having issues migrating my db. The error I was getting at that time was Incompatible Library version for `pg` gem, in which I then ran `gem pristine --all` and was able to migrate my db (currently using `postgresql version 12`).

Right after that is when I suddenly was not able to launch rails console anymore.

I also cannot check the rails version by doing `rails -v` because I get this same `undefined method 'request' for nil:NilClass` error. Although when I check `bundle show rails` I get `/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/rails-6.1.5`. I believe `rails 6.1.5` is the version I need to be using. I have tried uninstalling rails and reinstalling but that does not work.

Some more info about my environment:

- Bundle install is working, and postgres is up and running.
- ruby version `2.5.8`
- bundler version `2.2.5`
- rails version `6.1.5`
- postgres version `12`

Comment: `conflicting_dependencies' would suggest that there are some dependencies in your application which are probably interfering with each other. Maybe you could delete your Gemfile.lock file and try fresh gem installs? If that does not work you might want to add your Gemfile and lock file to the question.

Comment: Update your Ruby version. Ruby 2.5.8 was EOL 2021-04-05.  Ruby 2.7 is still getting security updates.